# Trying to access certain directories in Linux Amazon AWS instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

My specific problem is (and with it a lot of others).

I am trying to access: /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config

In my AWS Linux instance.

I'm using WinSCP and I was able to upload/download files in the home directory, but I can't seem to do so in any other directory.  Something about not having permissions.  I just don't know how to change permission settings in the Instance?  Or if it's a key problem?  Or something else?

Thanks for any help!

P.S.  Any tips on how to get a text editor onto the instance would be appreciated as well.

Comment: which user are you using to log on to the instance? What permissions does the user have?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I just needed to add the word sudo.  (Face palm)